# Pandas get the row value by column name in an apply function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> d = {'route1': ['a', 'b'], 'route2': ['c', 'd'], 'val1': [1,2]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
  route1 route2  val1
0      a      c     1
1      b      d     2
```

What I am trying to do is to pass a list that contains some column names and print the row value associated with that columns:

```
>>> def row_eval(row, list):
>>>    print(row.loc[list])
```

In the dataframe above, I first find all the columns that contains the name "route" and then apply the row_val func to each row. However I get the following err:

```
>>> route_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'route' in col]
>>> route_cols
['route1', 'route2']
>>> df.apply(lambda row: row_eval(row, route_cols)
KeyError: "None of [Index(['route1', 'route2'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Result should look like this:

```
route1 a
route2 c

route1 b
route2 d
```

Comment: Will you please add what the resulting df should look like?

Comment: In your sample output, is that 2 dataframes?

Comment: @dfundako no the function is being applying to each row individually. So the outputs are the values of the row['route1'] and row['route2'].

Answer (score 2):

Add `axis=1` to the apply function:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row_eval(row, route_cols), axis=1)
```

Without axis=1, you are iterating over the row index (column-wise). The row index are `0 1` instead of the column index `route1 route2` you want to match.  Hence, the error message.   What you want is to have row-wise operation (i.e. passing row to the apply function), then you need `axis=1`

Answer (score 1):

One way to print all of the values in these columns, is to iterate over all of the columns within a loop that iterates through all of the rows. Then to simply print the column name and the value together. The if statement is optional, but it will give a line break between rows, like in your example.

```
for idx in df.index:
    for column in route_cols:
        print(f'{column} {df.loc[idx, column]}')
        if column == route_cols[-1]:
            print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, you can use either `.melt()` or `.stack()` to get real close to your expected output. Not 100% sure if you're looking for 2 dataframes or not.

```
df[route_cols].stack()

0  route1    a
   route2    c
1  route1    b
   route2    d
dtype: object
    
df[route_cols].melt()

  variable value
0   route1     a
1   route1     b
2   route2     c
3   route2     d
```